# Gunicorn not creating socket on nginx

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to setup Django, Gunicorn and nginx.

I have configured Gunicorn in order to run, but it seems that I am experiencing a problem with nginx configuration to use Gunicorn.

Here is my configuration:

### /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=socket
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/pid
User=root
Group=root
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/srv/myproject/current
ExecStart=/srv/venvs/myenv/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/pid   \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/socket myapp.wsgi:application
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Gunicorn status looks like this

### sudo systemctl status gunicorn

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-01-18 23:32:11 UTC; 3min 23s ago
  Process: 6347 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6355 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 195.7M
      CPU: 1.426s
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─6355 /srv/venvs/myenv/bin/python3.6 /srv/venvs/myenv/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/pid --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/socket myapp.wsgi:application
           └─6360 /srv/venvs/myenv/bin/python3.6 /srv/venvs/myenv/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/pid --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/socket myapp.wsgi:application

Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server systemd[1]: Stopped gunicorn daemon.
Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server gunicorn[6355]: [2018-01-18 23:32:11 +0000] [6355] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server gunicorn[6355]: [2018-01-18 23:32:11 +0000] [6355] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn/socket (6355)
Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server gunicorn[6355]: [2018-01-18 23:32:11 +0000] [6355] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Jan 18 23:32:11 python-server gunicorn[6355]: [2018-01-18 23:32:11 +0000] [6360] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6360
```

My nginx configuration

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myserver-python

```
server {
    server_tokens off;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name         myserver.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.com.merged.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myserver.com.key;

    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    #access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.myserver.log;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.myserver.log;
    #error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.myserver.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.myserver.log;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn/socket;
    }
}
```

On the path `/run/gunicorn` I can see only `pid` file. File `socket` has never created.

This is how the error log looks like

### /var/log/nginx/error.myserver.log

```
2018/01/18 23:09:00 [crit] 5764#5764: *1 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn/socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 212.251.167.250, server: my-server.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn/socket:/",, host: "myserver.com"
```

Can anyone see what is wrong here? Why `socket` file is not made and `pid` file is made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The socket that gunicorn *actually* opened, as shown in the journal entries, differs from the socket configured in your systemd unit.

The journal shows what gunicorn actually did:

```
Jan 18 23:08:49 python-server gunicorn[5858]: [2018-01-18 23:08:49 +0000] [5858] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn/socket (5858)
```

Note that it actually opened `/run/gunicorn/socket`. But your nginx configuration and systemd unit specify to open `/run/gunicorn/gunicorn.socket`, which is a different path.

My first thought is that you probably changed the path in the systemd unit, but haven't run `systemctl daemon-reload`. Any changes in your systemd units won't take effect until you run this (or reboot).

Therefore, I would have systemd reload and then try restarting gunicorn.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart gunicorn.service
```

Comment: I will update my question with latest changes.

Comment: I updated my question with latest changes after reloading deamon and gunicorn.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration was correct, but the problem was that gunicorn service wasn't properly restarted.

Since the gunicorn was installed as systemd, it should be restarted with 
`systemctl restart gunicorn`.

After that it worked fine.

Comment: Well, I did say that you needed to restart gunicorn... :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wasn't sure was it working with `systemctl restart gunicorn.service`. Can you update your answer with `systemctl restart gunicorn` please? I accepted it as an answer.

Comment: I don't understand? My answer already says that!

Comment: @boban0987 `systemctl restart gunicorn == systemctl restart gunicorn.service`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason a gunicorn socket file will not be created or allow read/write access is due to SELinux blocking access.  SELinux is most common in RedHat / Fedora / CentOS flavors of Linux.

For instance, if you have SELinux running and the daemon creates a socket file outside of /run, /var/run, or a sub-directory below either of these, then on daemon restart the socket file will have the wrong file context. This would show up in the SELinux log (/var/log/audit/audit.log) as an error like:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1569976379.346:40651): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=25861 comm="httpd" path="/home/username/gunicorn.sock" 
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

You might also have an issue with a web server talking to the socket if the "user" or "group" permissions used by the web server process don't have access to read/write to the socket file. This may mean changing the User=root or Group=root (shown in the OP) within the systemd daemon's "Unit" file.

```
systemctl edit --full gunicorn.service
```

and then reloading the unit file and gunicorn

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn && systemctl status gunicorn
```